# python read text from table scraping

Tags: python, web-scraping, html-table, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

I need a value from table with website

My Python Code

```
import sys
import getopt
import linecache
import string
import ftplib
import os
import requests
from lxml import html
import datetime
page = requests.get(URL)
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
all_id = tree.xpath('//td[@style="display:none> &gt;"]/text()')
print 'Wszystkie ID:', all_id
```

website Code

```
<td style="display:none">id&gt;277918954,id32&gt;c14f940e3eed6a3871e1e3376048303f,level&gt;0,key_left&gt;0,key_right&gt;0,name&gt;file.png,type&gt;File png,size&gt;139.27 KB,hash&gt;538dd38791b76170ab71feec9ef6fed5</td>
```

I'm view only error, where is problem?

Comment: Could you please paste the imports too? I mean I imagine `requests` is the python package with the same name, but I'm not sure about the rest.

Comment: ok no problem, post updated

Answer (score 0):

> `//td[@style="display:none> &gt;"]/text()`

This would not match the presented element, this would:

```
//td[@style="display:none"]/text()
```

Though, this expression does not seem reliable.

To provide you with a reliable locator, we would need to see the complete HTML of the page, but, given what we have, how about checking that the text *starts with* `id`:

```
//td[starts-with(., "id")]/text()
```

Comment: @Grz3siu are you sure you actually have this element inside the `page.content`?

Comment: sorry, <div id="filesystem_grid_1" class="grid-view">

Comment: @Grz3siu not sure what you meant by the last comment.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative approach, you could use `BeautifulSoup` to extract all `<td>` elements with `display:none`. With this, I unescape all of the HTML entities (to convert `&gt;` into `>`), split the text on the commas, and for each entry in the list further split each entry based on the `>` to give you key/value pairs to construct a `params` dictionary:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import HTMLParser

h = HTMLParser.HTMLParser()
html = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

for td in soup.find_all('td', style=re.compile('display\s*:\s*none')):
    params = {}

    for p in h.unescape(td.text).split(','):
        k, v = p.split('>')
        params[k] = v

    print 'Id {}'.format(params['id'])
    print 'Id32 {}'.format(params['id32'])
```

This would display `id` and `id32` as follows:

```
Id 277918954
Id32 c14f940e3eed6a3871e1e3376048303f
```

`params` would hold all of the values:

```
{u'hash': u'538dd38791b76170ab71feec9ef6fed5', u'name': u'file.png', u'level': u'0', u'type': u'File png', u'key_right': u'0', u'key_left': u'0', u'id32': u'c14f940e3eed6a3871e1e3376048303f', u'id': u'277918954', u'size': u'139.27 KB'}
```

These could be displayed as follows:

```
for k, v in params.iteritems():
    print '{} : {}'.format(k, v)
```

Giving:

```
hash : 538dd38791b76170ab71feec9ef6fed5
name : file.png
level : 0
type : File png
key_right : 0
key_left : 0
id32 : c14f940e3eed6a3871e1e3376048303f
id : 277918954
size : 139.27 KB
```

---

If you already have a list of your `<td>` entries, the `id32`s could be displayed as follows:

```
entries = [
    'id>277918954,id32>c14f940e3eed6a3871e1e3376048303f,level>0,key_left>0,key_right>0,name>file.png,type>File png,size>139.27 KB,hash>538dd38791b76170ab71feec9ef6fed5',
    'id>277918891,id32>4029b601c64a573be83f1114ffee88ac,level>0,key_left>0,key_right>0,name>nn.py,type>File py,size>2.87 KB,hash>bc8e6fcd432053547ae9227daf1fc8bc',
    'id>277918001,id32>6bcd9fe60959a8798af2fea0db163792,level>0,key_left>0,key_right>0,name>new_100mb.test,type>File test,size>100 MB,hash>9b5183f05b62ca114c467945467050be',
    'id>277917368,id32>183ad6a4932d1a11016f63fc563b610d,level>0,key_left>0,key_right>0,name>new_100mb.test,type>File test,size>100 MB,hash>9b5183f05b62ca114c467945467050be',
    'id>277917219,id32>606e98d6d7a8ee286556e05752f71723,level>0,key_left>0,key_right>0,name>new_100mb.test,type>File test,size>100 MB,hash>9b5183f05b62ca114c467945467050be',
    'id>277916938,id32>2086038f425efaeeab7e91904c0a24bc,level>0,key_left>0,key_right>0,name>new_100mb.test,type>File test,size>100 MB,hash>9b5183f05b62ca114c467945467050be',
    'id>277915939,id32>5dc0b114317bb9b1250a20275cb5f7a5,level>0,key_left>0,key_right>0,name>100mb.test,type>File test,size>100 MB,hash>9b5183f05b62ca114c467945467050be']

for entry in entries:
    params = {}

    for p in entry.split(','):
        k, v = p.split('>')
        params[k] = v

    print 'Id32 {}'.format(params['id32'])
```

Giving you:

```
Id32 c14f940e3eed6a3871e1e3376048303f
Id32 4029b601c64a573be83f1114ffee88ac
Id32 6bcd9fe60959a8798af2fea0db163792
Id32 183ad6a4932d1a11016f63fc563b610d
Id32 606e98d6d7a8ee286556e05752f71723
Id32 2086038f425efaeeab7e91904c0a24bc
Id32 5dc0b114317bb9b1250a20275cb5f7a5
```

Comment: Martin, what when im need see all ID in source code ?, and if i have a ID how to print a id32?

Answer (score 0):

i'm used this code:

```
tree = html.fromstring(result.content)
bucket_elems = tree.findall(".//td[@style='display:none']")
bucket_names = [bucket_elem.text_content().replace("\n", "").strip() for bucket_elem in bucket_elems]
print bucket_names
```

Result:
http://pastebin.com/Cuv1KsnR

How to take only ID ?